# Audio stops after multiple times of pressing the button SDL C++

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have a problem when i press the button to play the sound clip/fx after couple of tries it just stops playing the sound. I am using SDL for this app bellow is the class sound.h with the sound.cpp

```
class Sound
{
private:
  SDL_AudioDeviceID deviceId;
  SDL_AudioSpec wavSpec;
  Uint32 wavLength;
  Uint8* wavBuffer;

public:
  Sound() {
    // SDL audio device init
       SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
}
  SDL_AudioDeviceID getID() { return deviceId; }
  Uint8* loadSound(const std::string& sound);
  bool play();
};
```

sound.cpp:

```
#include "Classes/Sound.h"

Uint8* Sound::loadSound(const std::string& sound)
{
   SDL_LoadWAV(sound.c_str(), &wavSpec, &wavBuffer, &wavLength);

   return wavBuffer;
 }

bool Sound::play()
{
    SDL_AudioDeviceID deviceId; 
    deviceId = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wavSpec, NULL, 0);
    int success = SDL_QueueAudio(deviceId, wavBuffer, wavLength);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(deviceId, 0);
    //SDL_FreeWAV(wavBuffer);

    //SDL_Delay(1);

   return success;
}
```

the declaration:

```
// sounds
Sound sndStart, sndStop, sndClick, sndCancel, sndWin;
SDL_AudioDeviceID deviceId = sndStart.getID();
Uint8* sndBufStart = sndStart.loadSound("gamedata/sounds/start.wav");
Uint8* sndBufStop = sndStop.loadSound("gamedata/sounds/stop.wav");
Uint8* sndBufClick = sndClick.loadSound("gamedata/sounds/click.wav");
Uint8* sndBufCancel = sndCancel.loadSound("gamedata/sounds/cancel.wav");
Uint8* sndBufWin = sndWin.loadSound("gamedata/sounds/win.wav");
```

and the call inside the main.cpp where the actual button is pressed:

```
 if (button(screen, &spinButton))
 {
    sndStart.play();
    clearItems();
    guessing->found(countLines);
    guessing->spin();
    clearItems();
    playAnimation(guessing, itemsRect);
    if (guessing->getLastWinning() > 0)
        sndWin.play();

  }
```